# Query not inserting, but not giving error either

Tags: php, mysql

I got this query and it's not inserting into the database but it's not giving an error either.

```
        try {
        $sth = $Db->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,phone,first_name) VALUES (:username,:password,:email,:phone,:firstname)");
        $sth->execute(array(':username' => $username,':password' => $password, ':email' => $email,':phone' => $phone,':firstname'=>$firstname));
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
```

[image]
I've tried inserting the query by command and it works fine. There are other insert queries on the site and those work fine too.. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: `perm` and `rank` don't need values?

Comment: @TiiJ7 nope. and I've tried adding them and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this?

```
try
{
    // Prepare Statement
    if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,phone,first_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)")))
        throw new Exception("Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error);

    // Bind Parms
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $email, $phone, $firstname))
        throw new Exception("Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);

    // Execute Statement
    if (!$stmt->execute())
        throw new Exception("Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    exit('Error: '. $ex->getMessage());
}
```

P.S. As `TiiJ7` suggestion on the comment to your question, are those two columns `perm` and `rank` - are they `nullable` columns? if not, you might have to specify a value at the time of row insertion.

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Ok for some reason you cannot put all those vars into bindParam so I've done it one by one. This is the error on the execute: Error: Execute failed: () (I've made it so the binds also throw an exeption and they don't)